# Android Service Connections

Tags: android, service, connection, exchange-server

I am developing an android application that runs a service off the main thread. It then runs another activity that exists in a seperate apk file. This apk needs to be able to spawn its own service and exchange information (complex objects) with the original service. They both share both services if that helps, as the services exist in a android library that both apk's reference. Is there any way to achieve this functionality? What are the limitations involved and is there any way they can be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

For Service 2 to communicate with Service 1 both have to be written by you. If by *'the services exist in a android library that both apk's reference'* you mean its an android system service then I don't think this would be possible unless you override the service definition.

If at all you are using android system services, you could try having a broadcast receiver in your Service 1 that is notified of all updates Service 2 may publish.

If the apps 1,2 and services 1,2 are all written by you then I do not think this is that difficult to achieve as you can share data using bundles in intents.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Both services are written by me. The problem seems to be accessing service 1 from service 2 inside apk 2. When I try this it tells me I dont have access to the service

`Intent gf = new Intent();
gf.setClassName("com.MyServices","com.MyServices.Service1");
bindService(gf, mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

It tells me I dont have permissions. If I try `Intent gf = new Intent("com.MyServices.Service1");` it just silently fails. No attempt will cause the `onServiceConnected` of my `mConnection` to fire.

Comment: Since you have cleared this a bit, let me just point out that I would rethink my design if I were you simply because you want both apk's to communicate with each other....what would happen if the user would uninstall on of the apk's? I am not sure what you want to achieve with the above setup but you could always exchange data between 2 different services within the same apk. There could be one other thing you could do if you still want to use different apk's : Use the same package name for both the apk's and then share a sqlite db file between them (have'nt tried that yet :P)

Comment: apk1 isnt dependent on apk2, only visa versa. If apk1 is uninstalled it will be understood that apk2 will no longer function. 

You say I can exchange data between 2 different services within the same apk, but I can exchange between 2 different apks if apk1 directly starts an activity on apk2?  To be honest im not entirely sure what my problem is so I am trying to determine if it is conceptually a problem before I start looking any deeper for a bug.

Comment: Starting an activity from another does not give the starter activity any kind of control...(for eg killing the starter activity does not kill the started activity, they live independently).                       Having a dependency such as yours is not a good design, anyway if keeping this design in mind you were to proceed then there are a few things you could try. Android has a few IPC methods you could try but then it all comes down to how complicated you want this to be and whether your app really need this complication.